# awk match last record and print

Tags: awk, gawk

I got this record as `fileinp`:

```
1 ABCDEFGHILM                12345678901234567   ABCD   X
1 CDEFGHILMNO                34567890123456789   BCDE   Y
1 EFGHILMNOPQ                56789012345678901   CDEF   Z
1 GHILMNOPQRS                78901234567890123   DEFG   W
```

When last character is Y or Z, I want to print from char 14 to char 47, appended by the last character matched.

Results expected as `fileout`:

```
        34567890123456789Y
        56789012345678901Z
```

I tried many codes but all fail,

```
gawk "{print /Y/ substr($1,14,33, length($1)-0)}" fileinp > fileout
```

Could you help me please?

In real word this is a full record, that's why I search for last chars

```
1 QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJK         ZXCVBNMLKJHGFDSAP   1234        12345678 12345ABCDEFGHIL12                                                                                                    202000Y
```

Comment: What does "from 13,33 and count it" mean here, exactly? it looks like you just want the string concatenation of the third and last fields

Comment: Yes string concatenation for sure, but could be counted how many raw are matched? Anyway count row could be done on output file

Comment: OK... and do you really need to match the last *byte*? or is it sufficient to match the last *character* - or the last space-separated field (`$NF`)?

Comment: last character of the record, it's always alphanumeric not space

Comment: Don't keep posting "answers" - [edit] your question to add any missing information you want to share with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sample input you provided where the last field is 1 chatracter:

```
$ awk '$NF~/[YZ]/{print substr($0,14,33) $NF}' file
                34567890123456789Y
                56789012345678901Z
```

For the real line of data you provided afterwards where the last field is multiple characters and making no assumptions about where the Y or Z might exist in that last field:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[YZ][^[:space:]]*$/){print substr($0,14,33) substr($0,RSTART,1)}' file
                34567890123456789Y
                56789012345678901Z
```

or if that Y or Z is always the last char in the line:

```
$ awk '/[YZ]$/{print substr($0,14,33) substr($0,length($0))}' file
                34567890123456789Y
                56789012345678901Z
```

Answer (score 0):

this is almost right, but missing Y or Z after new record

```
gawk "$NF~/Y|Z/{print substr($0,14,33)}" fileinp > fileout
```

Results:

```
        34567890123456789
        56789012345678901
```

Results expected:

```
        34567890123456789Y
        56789012345678901Z
```

Comment: Is this what solves your problem? That's not char 14 to 33, it is char 14 to 47. Can you please edit your question if that is what you meant?

Comment: sorry I mean starting from column 14 for next 33 chars

Comment: Please see the edit to your question. I assembled all you said in comments into there. Please try to always edit the question with the clarification requested, and do not respond in answers.

Comment: ok I modify first question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

i try this:

```
gawk "$NF~/Y|Z/{print substr($0,14,33) substr($0,194,1)}" fileinp > fileout
```

but I get this blank chars before last chars

```
    34567890123456789 Y
    56789012345678901 Z
```

I also try this and is works, but it's not really last chars:

```
gawk "$NF~/Y|Z/{print substr($0,14,33) substr($NF,7,1)}" fileinp > fileout

    34567890123456789Y
    56789012345678901Z
```

Comment: Try `awk '$NF~/^(Y|Z)$/{print substr($0,14,33) substr($0,length($0))}'` (fwiw I don't see anything GNU-specific here - any awk should handle this)

Comment: yes works, but without ~ I don't know why, maybe windows gawk.exe it's a bit different, thank you